# HTTPURLConnection gives responsecode :500, but works on restclient or postman in android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am getting `HTTPURLConnection` `responsecode as 500`. But when i pass the same parameters in `Postman/RestClient` using `Content-Type as application/json` it works and gives me the response. 
Following is my doPost method.

```
private String doPost(String jsonParam, String serviceUrl/*, String authorizeToken*/) {
        Log.e("doPost", "doPost called : URL : " + serviceUrl + "| jsonParam : " + jsonParam+"");
        HttpURLConnection urlConn;
        DataOutputStream printout;
        DataInputStream input;
        URL obj = null;
        String tempResponse = "";
        boolean error = false;
        try {
            obj = new URL(serviceUrl);
            urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            urlConn.setRequestMethod(POST);
            urlConn.setConnectTimeout(Constants.Connection.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            urlConn.setReadTimeout(Constants.Connection.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConn.setDoInput(true);

            // Send POST output.
            printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
            printout.write(jsonParam.toString().getBytes());
            printout.flush();
            printout.close();
            int responseCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();
            Log.e("doPost", "HTTP URL Connection responseCode :" + responseCode);
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                tempResponse = readStream(urlConn.getInputStream());
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            error = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (error) {
                tempResponse = "";
            }
        }
        return tempResponse;
    }
```

Can anyone help me to find my mistake, or resolve the issue? As I am not getting the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your user-agent by using

```
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; L39h;    Build/14.4.A.0.108; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.92 Mobile Safari/537.36 SogouMSE,SogouMobileBrowser/5.4.0");
```

which is an android browser user-agent. It workded for me for http://translate.google.com

if you don't set user-agent, a default one will be used. In my case it's

```
Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; L39h Build/14.4.A.0.108)
```

It might get rejected by some websites.